# htaccess - add language parameter to url

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I have page without language parameter in url, but I wold like to change it. I want to redirect all old urls, which exist on internet. For example the longest urls:
old url: http://www.(...).pl/oferty/mieszkania/pokaz/907912/
new url: http://www.(...).pl/pl/oferty/mieszkania/pokaz/907912/

I would like to redirect all regardless of length:
old url: http://www.(...).pl/*
new url: http://www.(...).pl/pl/*

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a code writing service - you are required to show some initial effort here.

Comment: What @CBroe said. You can try looking in here for a possible solution https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489
If it does not help please let us know what you tried.

Comment: Redirects can be implemented in a lot of ways. Your question doesn't give enough detail for anybody to help however. In order for someone to respond to your question, please give some more details: 1. What are you using to host the site (a third party service, Apache, Nginx, etc.) 2. What language or framework have you used to develop the site (Python Django, PHP, Java Spring Boot, etc.) 3. Do you want to redirect ALL previous traffic to the /pl/ url?

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(pl||en)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pl/$1 [R]
```